# Navigation drawer creates a shadow on the image button when drawer is dragged

Tags: android, camera, navigation-drawer, android-imagebutton

I am having trouble when trying to drag navigation drawer on top of an image button. When the drawer button is dragged at first, it creates a shadow on the top of image button and then the drawer comes out. How to stop drawer creating a shadow on top of my imagebutton?

When the navigation drawer is pulled from left:
[image: Navigation drawer on top of camera preview]

When the navigation drawer is completely on the screen:
[image: Navigation drawer when getting dragged]

Also, please note that Imagebutton has no shadows on its own when drawer is closed.Please help me. I need to fix it immediately. I tried searching a lot but the solution i found make imagebutton background null or transparent color, which is not helping me here as imagebutton background only gets screwed when drawer is pulled out.

Comment: is it still the same when pressed?

Comment: When pressing the imagebutton, there is no shadow over it..Only when the drawer is dragged out.

Comment: try to `invalidate` the `imageButton`after the nav_drawer has been pulled from left.

Comment: Nothing worked out. So now I am shifting my activity to right when drawer opens.